# SELECT multiple rows from single column into single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write an SQL Server query that will retrieve data from the following example tables:

```
Table: Person
ID      Name
--      ----
1       Bill
2       Bob
3       Jim

Table: Skill
ID      SkillName
--      -----
1       Carpentry
2       Telepathy
3       Navigation
4       Opera
5       Karate

Table: SkillLink
ID      PersonID        SkillID
--      --------        -------
1       1               2
2       3               1
3       1               5
```

As you can see, the SkillLink table's purpose is to match various (possibly multiple or none) Skills to individual Persons. The result I'd like to achieve with my query is:

```
Name    Skills
----    ------
Bill    Telepathy,Karate
Bob     
Jim     Carpentry
```

So for each individual Person, I want a comma-joined list of all SkillNames pointing to him. This may be multiple Skills or none at all.

This is obviously not the actual data with which I'm working, but the structure is the same.

Please also feel free to suggest a better title for this question as a comment since phrasing it succinctly is part of my problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Comment: From the title you might think that, but as you see that's not quite right. I'm wanting to concatenate many rows into a single text string AND pair them with their Persons based on a third table. I'm looking for the query that will do *all* of this, not just the concatenation.

Comment: Re: question title - You could omit "SQL query", as that's evident from the tags, and change "combine" to "select".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've made the change, but the title still neglects to mention that I'm trying to do this using data from 3 tables. One with data about Persons, one with data about Skills, and one linking the two. I think that's integral to my question, but I don't know how to articulate it.

Comment: Don't worry about getting all that in the title. Just a general, high level outline of your problem is enough. The bit about the three tables is important to the question, but it's OK that it's not in the title, so long as it's in the question body.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You would use `FOR XML PATH` for this:

```
select p.name,
  Stuff((SELECT ', ' + s.skillName 
         FROM skilllink l
         left join skill s
           on l.skillid = s.id 
         where p.id = l.personid
         FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') Skills
from person p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e1f4/9)

Result:

```
| NAME |            SKILLS |
----------------------------
| Bill | Telepathy, Karate |
|  Bob |            (null) |
|  Jim |         Carpentry |
```

Comment: The `.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')` is unnecessary. If you're worried about not having enough space for the data type, then do a `CAST`/`CONVERT` on `s.SkillName` to `varchar(max)`. IE: `SELECT ', ' + CAST(s.SkillName AS VARCHAR(MAX))...`

Comment: No, I mean you don't need the `,TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')` part after the `FOR XML PATH`. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e1f4/9

Comment: @SPFiredrake fixed. :)  Its been a long day

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is something like SQL Server's FOR XML PATH('') which combines results as a rowset

```
Select Person.Name, 
  (
     Select SkillName + ',' 
     From SkillLink 
     inner join skill on skill.id = skilllink.skillid
     Where SkillLink.PersonID = Person.ID FOR XML PATH('')
  )
as Skills
FROM Person
```

Comment: Please use the table names and column names from the given examples.

Comment: This works and I really like the simplicity. However, the result includes unnecessary commas. I'm going with bluefeet's answer due to clearer writing and a cleaner result, but I wanted to thank you for giving me a working answer!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is something like SQL Server's FOR XML PATH
which combines results as a rowset