# How to select all column values as one row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

This is my table values:

```
-----------------------------
   id | rackname | routeid |
-----------------------------
  1   | rack1    |   1    
  2   | rack2    |   1
  3   | rack3    |   2
  4   | rack4    |   1
  5   | rack5    |   2
  6   | rack6    |   1
  .
  .
  .
```

I need to select only one row form this table that need to select all the values based on routeid using SQL Server 2014.

I need to generate a row like this..

```
---------------------------------------------------
id  | rackname1 | rackname2 | rackname3 | rackname4....
---------------------------------------------------
 1  | rack1     | rack2     | rack4     | rack6    ...
```

How to generate this result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What variety of SQL are you using?  And will there only ever be 6 racks?

Comment: Please format your question property. You can check guidelines how to ask question and is it SQL- Server question or for oracle or for mysql?

Comment: If SQL Server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server

Comment: its sql server and now its having 15 rackds in future it may change

Comment: thanks adrian. but i need to generate only one row based on route id.

Comment: Show us what you tried from the pivot examples.

Comment: i tried like this but i can't understand this.   select * from (  select rackname, id  from racks ) src pivot(  sum(id)
  for rackname in ([1], [2], [3], [4]) ) racks;   Now m studying pivot..

Comment: Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730484/select-multiple-rows-from-single-column-into-single-row

Answer (score 1):

You can do with `PL/SQL`

Declare table type variable (At the end you need to `pivot` on this variable so make sure for structure).

Now push desire data on this `table`.

Then `pivot` this table.

Comment: SQL Server has no PL/SQL

Comment: PL/SQL means you cannot not do with simple one line sql query.