# codeigniter join table technique

Tags: php, codeigniter

Guys on my database i have three tables containing data as shown on a link below.
 On tables **class and subjects**, *ssid and csid* are foreign key from  *members*.

I joining tables using left join as shown in model code shown below. 
when i echo *first_name, surname and class_name* for `John claudius` it appears three times while for `Alex massawe` it appear only once.
 but if i add information for `Alex massawe` result will displayed out as many times as information for `Alex massawe` 
that are within subjects. 
I need your help so that information given out will not be repeated if add information on tables **subjects** for a person whose name already in tables members.

### Tables within database

members

sid           first_name          surname
a001        alex                          massawe
a002        John                        claudius

class

id             csid          class_name
01           a001          baby_class
02           a002          Class_one

subjects

id         ssid       subject_name
01        a002     Mathematics
02       a002      literature
03        a002     Communication skills
04        a001         Mathematics

result table

sid            first_name           surname            class_name
a002           John                          claudius               Class_one
a002           John            claudius              Class_one
a002           John                          claudius               Class_one
a001           alex                          massawe              baby_class

### codes

Models:

> function get_particular($sid){
>      $this->db->select('*');
>   $this->db->from('members m');
>  $this->db->join('subjects s',
>   'm.sid=s.ssid', 'left');
>  $this->db->join('class c',
>   'm.sid=c.csid', 'left');
>  $this->db->where('m.sid', $sid);
>   $query = $this->db->get();
>   return $query->result_array(); 
>       }

Controller:

> function particular($sid){
>      $sid=$this->uri->segment(3);
>   $this->load->model('names');
>
> $this->data["names"]=$this->names_rank->get_particular($sid);
>     $this->load->view("view/details", $this->data); 
>  }

view:

> foreach($names as $name)        {
>
> echo $name['sid'].' '. $name['first_name'].' '. $name['surname'].'
>   '.$name['class_name'];
>   }

Comment: But you did not pass model in your view

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13731188/4229270

Comment: It is because you have NOT assigned any subject to this sid. And there is no link between the class and subjects too. When you have rows added for Alex Massawe in subjects table, you would see the results properly. –

Comment: Why are you using LEFT join .... pls consider removing it. It causes the duplicates.

Comment: okay, how can i join tables?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the foreach loop just echo the result

`echo $names['sid'].' '. $names['first_name'].' '. $names['surname'].' '.$names['class_name'];`

If you need to loop,  try loop foreach member then echo $names